# In AM modulation how is an electrical signal mixed with the carrier wave?

Tags: radio, wave, electromagnetic

I may have the wrong stack exchange to ask this beginners question. Should this be a physics question?  The interference of waves constitutes the addition and subtraction of wave forms. In AM modulation a voice signal is somehow "mixed", "superimposed", "modulated", "coded" with a carrier signal. I have heard it described in those four manners.  I assume it is not interference of two electrical wave signals and cannot be an addition. There lies my problem. Can someone first explain. Is the electrical signal in the wire in the form of an electromagnetic wave? and How are these two separate signals  ( i.e. one being a carrier wave and one being a signal from a voice ) modulated together?  I cannot understand how this is physically done nor a mechanical analogy to this as I can with wave interference.  Thank you.

Comment: for modulation substitute multiplied

Comment: Please not to be taking offence, but... A pedant writes: it's not AM modulation. AM stands for amplitude modulation. It's amplitude modulation or AM, not AM modulation; the latter means you're writing amplitude modulation modulation, which is just silly. :)

Answer (score 2):

> In AM modulation how is an electrical signal mixed with the carrier
>   wave?

For AM the usual way is to use analogue multiplication i.e. the two signals are fed to a multiplier. The output consists of sum and difference signals i.e. you get sidebands. There is no longer any baseband (well there is no intention but a little will leak through): -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](http://www.slideshare.net/durgeshsuthar92/amplitude-modulation-30636818)

You get sum and difference frequencies because that is what happens when you multiply sin a with sin b: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you , this is very helpful.  Since I cannot vote because this is my first question on this site I put a comment below to help further clarify my intuition.

Comment: @Sedumjoy if you are happy with this (or any other) answer to your question, please consider formally accepting it. If you have further questions, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the electrical signal in the wire in the form of an electromagnetic wave?

The electrical signal in the wire is... an electrical signal. Only when it is transmitted through an antenna is it then an electromagnetic wave.

> How are these two separate signals ( i.e. one being a carrier wave and one being a signal from a voice ) modulated together?

Lets take your example of encoding a voice signal being encoded into an AM signal:

Voice is transmitted using sound waves. A microphone converts sound waves that hit the microphone into an electrical signal. 
Separately, an electrical carrier signal can be generated using an oscillator. Then these two signals can be multiplied together using analog circuitry and transmitted. During transmission they are converted from electrical signals to electromagnetic waves through the antenna.

Comment: This is my first question on this site so I really can't vote but perhaps you can explain your sentence " multiplexed together using analog circuitry and transmitted". This is where my intuition is breaking down. Is there a way you can show how this is done? Multiplying sin waves together is a mathematical construction.  How is it that electrons in the wire  ( that you say is now an electrical  signal ) are now doing this?  Thank you

Comment: That gets a bit complicated. I would recommend looking up operational amplifiers to understand how math functions can be applied to electrical signals

Comment: I found an op amp tutorial on YOu tube...200 video's.  I better get started huh?     Did the inventor of the crystal radio have this sort of training?  Reason I ask ....the diode demodulates the signal in a crystal radio.  How was that device built without the people who built it being engineers in signal processing? or perhaps they were in disguise, or got lucky.  Charles Harrold built an arc fone in 1906 that used a carrier wave but I don't think he had any formal training. How can someone guess the mathematical function on the electric signal? very curious.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to generate AM
1) use a high-power voice amplifier to vary the plate voltage of the final RF amplifier

2) use Motorola MC1590, or MC1596, or similar from Analog Devices, to vary the carrier amplitude, as a realtime copy of the low frequency information

3) literally generate the sidebands and sum them; AM sidebands are counter-rotating vectors, so the phases cancel and only amplitude remains; if you produce imperfectly-cancelling sidebands, you have a mix of AM and PM